# CARTO: centered icons instead coloured countries

Tags: carto

In CARTO I'm making a [tourists per country map](https://masti.carto.com/builder/e473feb6-739f-11e7-82b1-0ef24382571b/embed)

Instead of colouring countries, I'd like to put a centered Bagpack icon in the middle of every country, of size depending on the amount of tourists.

When I use Centroid analysis, it deletes my `amount_of_tourists` column. So how to do that?

Comment: Convert polygons to centroid and follow this guide [to add bagpack as symbol](https://carto.com/learn/guides/styling/style-point-data-with-marker-images). To set icon size, go to `Style / 2 Style / Fill` and select `By value / amount_of_tourists'

Comment: Hey @aldo_tapia this could be an answer instead of a comment. :-)